# In pytorch, how to train a model with two or more outputs?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

```
output_1, output_2 = model(x)
loss = cross_entropy_loss(output_1, target_1)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

loss = cross_entropy_loss(output_2, target_2)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

However, when I run this piece of code, I got this error:

```
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [1, 4]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

Then, I really wanna know what I am supposed to do to train a model with 2 or more outputs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire premise on which pytorch (and other DL frameworks) is founded on is the backporpagation of the gradients of a **scalar** loss function.
In your case, you have a **vector** (of dim=2) loss function:

```py
[cross_entropy_loss(output_1, target_1), cross_entropy_loss(output_2, target_2)]
```

You need to decide how to combine these two losses into a *single* scalar loss.
For instance:

```py
weight = 0.5  # relative weight
loss = weight * cross_entropy_loss(output_1, target_1) + (1. - weight) * cross_entropy_loss(output_2, target_2)
# now loss is a scalar
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Hi @Shai, thanks for your answer. I wonder if this means that I need to specify the weight of output_1 and output_2 (i.e. how much they contribute to the gradient) and then put them into one scalar?

Comment: side note: do not use "lambda" as a variable name as it is a Python reserved keyword (it won't work).

Comment: @YukiWang you obviously need to decide which one is more important. What is the meaning of having one model performing two different tasks? what if the tasks contradicts each other? this is why _mathematically_ you have a single scalar loss at the end.

Comment: @Shai, The reason why the model performs two tasks at the same time is that these two tasks are related. I just wanna use this way to evaluate the usability of a multi-task model.

Comment: @YukiWang multi-task is great and it usually improve performance. But _mathematically_ you need to provide a _scalar_ output.